# Django templates how loop through rows of a model

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to for loop through rows of a model into a table. It would also be very useful if i could exclude certain fields. I am making a form that the user can create by creating there own questions to ask in one model and a model for the answers

For example:

model.py

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield()
    Question1 = models.Charfield()
    Question2 = models.Charfield()
    ect

class Answers(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Questions, related_name='question')
    qustion_no = models.IntegerField()
    answer = models.Charfield()
```

form.html

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>Question</th>
       <th>Answers</th> 
   </tr>
   {% for q in Questions %}
       <tr>
           <td>{{q}}</td>
           <td>{{q.question}}</td
       </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: I don't understand this question really. Of course you can loop through the rows, by iterating over eg `Question.objects.all()`. What are you actually asking?

Comment: Say i have a page called questionnaires. I would use Question.objects.all() to show all the questionnaires. I then click on a Questionnaire to view the answers of that questionnaire next to the question in a table. The way i know how to do it is using {{questions.question1}} ect. But then i can not for loop through the answers as each row will have question 1 as the question

Comment: Well, that's not looping through rows, it's looping through columns. But your model is completely broken. Why have separate fields questions? Your Question model should contain *one* question. Not related, but it makes no sense to set related_name from Answer to Question as "question". It should be "answers".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you may searching for something like this.

```
 <table>
   <tr>
     <th>Question</th>
     <th>Answers</th> 
   </tr>
   {% for q in Questions %}
   <tr>
   {% for a in q.question.all %}
       <td>{{q}}</td>
       <td>{{a.answer}}</td>
   {% endfor %}
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: It seems that you some how understand what I am trying to do lol. I get an error though saying: TypeError at /questionnaires/get/2/
'Questions' object is not iterable

Comment: Here you are passing obect of a Question so you can directly use `{% for a in q_object.question.all %}
       <td>{{q_object}}</td>
       <td>{{a.answer}}</td>
   {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [django-tables2](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

It is pretty flexible and can be modified easily